# Which file holds the Create and Import from V card menu options?

Tags: php, suitecrm

I need to have some modules (mostly custom already) where the users are allowed to edit the information on a record (IE - update notes that they called the client), but need to not allow them to create a new client record either from the quick menu on the left, or the client-> drop down menu.. I checked in the menu.php file, made a copy into my custom module folder to override, but that didn't remove it. I tried toying with roles, but it doesn't seem that there is a way that the user can edit, but not create (only Edit option - seems all or nothing).

Comment: This seems to be more of a support question for suitecrm than a programming question. I would recommend try asking in their [forum](https://community.suitecrm.com/) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the redirect!!! I will look there for sure.

Comment: Hey @jkortus, one thing you can do is to have to the separate team and using code you can check if use trying to create a new record or edit the record and according to that you may restrict them.